# Alternative way to draw custom stuff on screen in GTK3?

Tags: c, gtk3

I am aware only with one way to draw custom things on screen - GTKDrawArea using Cairo

This is what I have made:
[image]
Is there other ways to archieve something like this, which are less resouce heavy, than completly redrawing screen 60 times per second? If not, does there exists option for optimisation (like using layers, so grid is not redrawed each frame or rendering entire scheme at once and then shifting it around)?

Edit: I forgot to mention GtkGlArea, but it is extremly hard to use in this aplication, so I deemed it as not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very wide question, I'll have a go.

You can use [GtkGLArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html), that allows you to render using OpenGL which can be more low-level and thus faster than going through Cairo. It does of course make you do a lot more work.

You can also create an off-screen image and render the entire schematic to that, then just copy a suitable rectangle to match the current scroll location, that can probably be faster than doing lots of drawing.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention GtkGLArea. I tried to use that before, but I gave up. It is absalute nightmare.

Comment: @Bumbieris112 It looks pretty doable, ordinary 2D graphics is not too hard to do with OpenGL, there are plenty of tutorials for it. Just enable orthographic projection and go at it, first perhaps using old-school begin/end style (if that's still available).

Comment: Well, old style is not avaliable. Now there is need for shader compilations... Which is absalute nightmare.